# lapply to turn specified matrix elements within list to NA

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have a list of matrices (toy example):

```
x <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)
y <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

l <- list(x ,y)
```

I need to turn some elements >= 11 into NA.

Outside of the list I would just use

```
x[(x>= 11)] <- NA
```

but trying to lapply the same function appears to apply it to each matrix as a whole (ie each matrix turns into a single NA value).

```
l_na <- lapply(l, function(x) x[(x >= 11)] <- NA)
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about lapply. A solution and any pointers of what I am getting wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
l_na <- lapply(l, function(x) { x[(x >= 11)] <- NA; x })
l_na

##[[1]]
##     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
##[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
##
##[[2]]
##     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
##[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Adding the `x` as a return value like above is one option.  I don't know if there are others.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `replace`

```
l_na <- lapply(l, function(x) replace(x, x>=11, NA))
l_na
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Or with some golfing

```
lapply(l, function(x) x*NA^(x>=11))
```