# Using lapply to create 0's in upper triangle of a list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have a list of matrices of mostly similar sizes. I need to keep the upper triangle of each matrix equal to 0. I can make the upper tri of an individual matrix equal to 0 by using:

```
matrix[upper.tri(matrix)] <- 0
```

When I try to apply this to the list of matrices using `lapply` it replaces the entire matrix list with 0's. For example:

```
list.matrix <- lapply(list.matrix, function (x) x[upper.tri(x)] <- 0)

$`matrix1`
[1] 0
$`matrix2`
[1] 0
...
```

Can anyone provide input as to why this might be happening?

Comment: `function (x) { x[upper.tri(x)] <- 0; return(x) }` https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved by including the function in `lapply` as a new function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x[upper.tri(x)] <- 0
  x
}
```

as suggested here: [lapply to turn specified matrix elements within list to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701393/lapply-to-turn-specified-matrix-elements-within-list-to-na).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
f <- function(x) replace(x, upper.tri(x), 0)
f(m1)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
```